# NodeJS NEXE bundle error

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to use NEXE to bundle my express 4 project. The bundling was sucessful, and a http_server.nex was generated. However, when I was trying to run the bundled file, I got the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '..../release/types/mime.types'
```

And I checked the release folder, the types folder and the mime.types file was never created. Any suggestions?

Or in general, what's the best way to deploy node project in a package? I tried several tools but none seem work so far. We need some level of obfuscation / compilation to have some code security.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I think you asked it here too: https://github.com/jaredallard/nexe/issues/144